# Alterar background de acordo com a frequência

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer uma tabela que recebe os números vindos de uma consulta SQL e conforme a frequência de cada um deles, alterar o background.

Um exemplo (retirado de um site na internet):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Recebo um `array()` como o seguinte da consulta (exemplo):

```
Array(
    [intConcurso] => 1599
    [dataConcurso] => 2017 - 12 - 15
    [num0] => 1
    [num1] => 3
    [num2] => 4
    [num3] => 5
    [num4] => 6
    [num5] => 8
    [num6] => 9
    [num7] => 10
    [num8] => 14
    [num9] => 18
    [num10] => 20
    [num11] => 21
    [num12] => 22
    [num13] => 23
    [num14] => 25
)
```

Com isso tentei o seguinte:

```
<? 
if ($f["num0"] == "1") {
    if ($freq_1 == 1) {
        $cor_1 = "#e7b5b5";
        $freq_1++;
    } elseif ($freq_1 == 2) {
        $cor_1 = "#de8c8c";
        $freq_1++;
    } elseif ($freq_1 == 3) {
        $cor_1 = "#d66363";
        $freq_1++;
    } elseif ($freq_1 == 4) {
        $cor_1 = "#ef4a4a";
        $freq_1++;
    } else {
        $cor_1 = "#db0000";
        $freq_1++;
    }
} else {
    $cor_1 = "#ffffff";
    $freq_1 = 1;
}
?>
<td style="background-color: <?= $cor_1 ?>; margin: 20px 0;"> 1 </td>
```

Isso para cada número do ***1*** ao ***25***. Como são muitos dados criei um loop que fizesse isso:

```
<?php
for ($p = 0; $p <= 14; $p++) { // $f['num0'] a $f['num14']
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 25; ++$i) { // números 1 a 25
        echo htmlspecialchars('<? ') . '<br>';
        echo 'if ($f["num' . $p . '"] == "' . $i . '") {' . '<br>';
        echo 'if ($freq_' . $i . ' == 1) {' . '<br>';
        echo '$cor_' . $i . ' = "#e7b5b5";' . '<br>';
        echo '$freq_' . $i . '++;' . '<br>';
        echo '}' . '<br>';
        echo 'elseif ($freq_' . $i . ' == 2) {' . '<br>';
        echo '$cor_' . $i . ' = "#de8c8c";' . '<br>';
        echo '$freq_' . $i . '++;' . '<br>';
        echo '}' . '<br>';
        echo 'elseif ($freq_' . $i . ' == 3) {' . '<br>';
        echo '$cor_' . $i . ' = "#d66363";' . '<br>';
        echo '$freq_' . $i . '++;' . '<br>';
        echo '}' . '<br>';
        echo 'elseif ($freq_' . $i . ' == 4) {' . '<br>';
        echo '$cor_' . $i . ' = "#ef4a4a";' . '<br>';
        echo '$freq_' . $i . '++;' . '<br>';
        echo '} else {' . '<br>';
        echo '$cor_' . $i . ' = "#db0000";' . '<br>';
        echo '$freq_' . $i . '++;' . '<br>';
        echo '}' . '<br>';
        echo '} else {' . '<br>';
        echo '$cor_' . $i . ' = "#ffffff";' . '<br>';
        echo '$freq_' . $i . ' = 1;' . '<br>';
        echo '}' . '<br>';
        echo '?>' . '<br>';
        echo  htmlspecialchars('<td style="background-color: ') . htmlspecialchars('<?= ') . '$cor_' . $i . htmlspecialchars(' ?>') . ';' . htmlspecialchars(' margin: 20px 0;"> ' . $i . ' </td>');
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

A página completa ficaria aqui:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="resultadoFiltro">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
                    Frequência das dezenas
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body" style="overflow-x: scroll;">
                    <div class="row center">
                        <div class="col-sm-12" style="">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="center"> Conc </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 1 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 2 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 3 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 4 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 5 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 6 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 7 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 8 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 8 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 10 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 11 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 12 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 13 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 14 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 15 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 16 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 17 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 18 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 19 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 20 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 21 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 22 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 23 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 24 </th>
                                        <th class="center"> 25 </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php                                                         
                                    foreach ($resultados_sorteios as $f) {
                                        $f = array_unique($f);
                                        $freq_1 = 1;
                                        $freq_2 = 1;
                                        $freq_3 = 1;
                                        $freq_4 = 1;
                                        $freq_5 = 1;
                                        $freq_6 = 1;
                                        $freq_7 = 1;
                                        $freq_8 = 1;
                                        $freq_9 = 1;
                                        $freq_10 = 1;
                                        $freq_11 = 1;
                                        $freq_12 = 1;
                                        $freq_13 = 1;
                                        $freq_14 = 1;
                                        $freq_15 = 1;
                                        $freq_16 = 1;
                                        $freq_17 = 1;
                                        $freq_18 = 1;
                                        $freq_19 = 1;
                                        $freq_20 = 1;
                                        $freq_21 = 1;
                                        $freq_22 = 1;
                                        $freq_23 = 1;
                                        $freq_24 = 1;
                                        $freq_25 = 1;
                                    ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td> <?= $f['intConcurso'] ?> </td>
                                            <!-- Aqui fica o resultado do loop criado no código acima -->
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Mesmo assim não está dando certo. Estou viajando em alguma parte aqui na minha lógica ou há alguma outra forma mais enxuta de fazer?

Comment: De onde vem os valores das frequências?

Comment: Qual a lógica de atribuição das gamas de vermelho às várias frequências ?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss quais valores? Eles não tem valores. Apenas os setados por mim logo após o `foreach()`, onde começo todos com 1. @Isac para demonstrar que o número está saíndo muitas vezes.

Comment: Mas a cor de fundo não variará conforme a frequência? Como não tem valores?

Comment: Veja bem, os valores (números que saíram no concurso) vem do banco de dados. Apenas isso. Dessa forma eu meio que "conto" se o número X saiu 1 vez, 2 vezes, 3 vezes. Enfim, talvez minha lógica esteja errada.

Comment: "para demonstrar que o número está saíndo muitas vezes" Mas o 25 parece-me menos vermelho que o 19 por exemplo. Não consegui perceber a correlação entre as cores e os numeros.

Comment: @Isac a imagem não tem relação com o meu código, foi retirado de um site na internet. Foi só para exemplificar. Editei a pergunta com essa informação.

Comment: As frequencias são os valores que vem em `num0`, `num1`, etc ?

Comment: @Isac o que vem em `num0`, `num1` etc, são os números sorteados na loteria. São os números sorteados do dia. Eles mudam a cada sorteio. Os números variam de ***1*** a ***25***.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss através do que você comentou, tive uma luz e consegui resolver. Muito obrigado!